# User returning nil. Not sure what to do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am trying to display the name of the user who posted an item. Only thing is that `Item.last.user` == `nil`.

I've set up the `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationships in the models already.

Here is the params hash of the items controller:

```
def item_params
  params.require(:item).permit(:name, :quantity, :boughtfor, :soldfor, :user_id)
end
```

Notice that I `:user_id` is there.

Schema for items:

```
  create_table "items", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.integer  "boughtfor"
    t.integer  "soldfor"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

How can I make the user not `nil`?

**UPDATES**

create action in items controller:

```
  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: One thing that would help is to have validations on `Item` and constraints on the database table to make sure the user is always set.  Check your Rails server log output. Do you see any warnings about unpermitted parameters? Are you sure the `user_id` is set properly?

Comment: Also, what does your `Item` new form look like? Is it a nested form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this way

```
@item = current_user.items.new(item_params)
```

This will take id of the current user. current_user refers to the signed in user

Comment: In the create action?

Comment: yes, only if a currrent_user object is present. I suppose only signed in users are able to create items. Am I right?

Comment: Trying out this solution now.

Comment: okay, are you using devise for authentication? because current_user object is available in devise. If you are using any other gem for authentication then refer to the docs to see what object to be used which refers to the signed in user

Comment: Yeah I'm using Devise.

Comment: if you're using devise then indeed you need to try the solution RSB gave. however, do try to check first if the current_user is defined, otherwise you would end up with the same problem. can users access the item creation without being logged in?

Comment: @Cremz is right, you need to put this action under devise authentecate_user! filter otherwise it will throw error.
Dylan - you are welcome buddy

Answer (score 0):

when you create the migration you can setup

```
 t.integer  "user_id", null: false
```

or you can define the relation on the database level:

```
t.belongs_to :user, index: true
```

make sure you actually have the user id when you are trying to create the item. Are you using a form? How are you grabbing the user id? Is it from devise?

Comment: This line - `add_index "items", ["user_id"], name: "index_items_on_user_id"` is in the code. Does it do the same thing?

Comment: Nope, you still need the null: false in order for the database to not save items without the user. However, you still need to send the user it to the create item method. show us that method

Comment: Updated the original post with the create action.

Comment: Can you post the view with the form for creating the Item?